# KDE Plasma not searching more than 1 letter in the start menu

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I recently install KDE plasma on top of my vanilla Ubuntu environment and for some reason the start menu doesn't search for anything more than 1 letter with it being stuck at whatever key I press first. It is a very strange bug and I am under the assumption that it's because of some kind of system conflict.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. All started when the IBus Panel appeared on the Notification Area.
When I switch to "Application Dashboard" alternative, all characters goes. And when I switch to "Appliation Menu", the search doesn't work at all.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

As @Guilhermo mentioned in comments, it may have something to do with IBus Panel. I also have same problem if IBus Panel is turned off (and layout management is done with KDE settings). And **if I start IBus Panel (or IBus Preferences, which in turn runs panel), I can use main menu without any problems**.

Unfortunately, "IBus Panel" is not an ideal solution for me (can't setup caps-lock to switch layouts), so I hope somebody will find another fix.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed KDE Plasma on my Ubuntu Unity 22.04 because Unity is starting to show its age.
I also had this problem of the start menu search bar only accepting one keypress, but after a reboot it now works fine. Both on X11 and Wayland. While the problem lasted I could get more keypresses in by hovering my mouse over different search results. Whenever the highlight moved to another result it accepted one more keypress.